# UITextView not refreshing

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextview, appdelegate

I am trying to integrate the "Open with..." functionality.

In my `AppDelegate.m` I have

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
...
_fileContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url
                                                encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                   error:&error];
...
ViewController *vc = (ViewController*)self.window.rootViewController;
        [vc refreshUI:nil];
}
```

I am using ARC, so I only call the following in my `ViewController.h` and later omit the `@synthesize` in the `.m`

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextView *textView;
```

In my `ViewController.m` I have the following

```
-(void)refreshUI:(id)sender
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    if ([appDelegate openedFromURL])
    {
        NSLog(@"[refreshUI] appDelegate openFromURL (Length: %d)", [appDelegate.fileContent length]);
        NSLog(@"Contents before: %@", [_textView text]);
        [_textView setText:appDelegate.fileContent];
        NSLog(@"Contents after: %@", [_textView text]);
    }
...
}
```

When I go to open my file form another application (Dropbox), the first NSLog gives me the right length of my file. The second NSLog gives me the correct "old" contents of the UITextView and the third NSLog gives me the correct "new" contents (begin the contents of the file I "opened with..." through the dropbox app). So the data does make it to my app.

THe problem is the UITextView does not get updated. If I press any other button in the UIViewController (which causes me to switch to a different UIViewController) and then go back to "ViewController" the UITextView is updated with the correct data. Even if I add an UIButton to and set its action to only call `[self refreshUI]` the UITextView updates.

It just doesn't refresh on its own from the method being called from AppDelegate.

What am I doing wrong? I even tried manually redrawing the UITextView with `setNeedsDisplay`. But that had no effect.

Thanks

Comment: My first guess would be that you are calling `stringWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:` on a background thread, like you should, but not calling `refreshUI:` on the main thread. `UIKit` loves throwing out calls made on a background thread.

Comment: I did not consciously call `stringWithContensOfURL` in a background thread to avoid such a problem... does it happen on it's own? The `refreshUI` statement is only a couple of lines after the `stringWithContensOfURL` and both are in the same method.

Comment: And judging by the three NSLog statements it "gets there" in time - right? Would it be a solution to save the value of _fileContent in `NSUserDefaults` and then use a `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` to trigger `refreshUI` which then just reads what is in the `NSUserDefaults`

Comment: Try wrapping the `refreshUI:` call in a dispatch block to the main thread like so:`dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{[vc refreshUI:nil];});` If that works then it's probably a threading issue.

Comment: the `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{[vc refreshUI:nil];});` had no change in behavior.

Comment: Even if I put both `stringWithContentsOfURL` and `refreshUI` in to the block the UITextView still does not get updated.

Comment: I added a `[_textView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];` right before `[_textView setText:appDelegate.fileContent];`. The UITextView remains white. I checked/double checked the hooking up in IB and everything is fine. Could it be that the methods get called on `_textView` before it is even "loaded"? The same statement in i.e. `viewDidAppear` changes the color of the UITextView - so it is hooked up correctly.

Comment: Yes, it is definitely possible. That's what I would check next. Try putting this in your `refreshUI:` method: `NSLog(@"address of textfield is %p",self.textView);`. Open a url through your app, and then hit that manual refresh button. If the address has changed then you are writing text to a textfield that is being replaced. Also, I know the textView is hooked up correctly since the manual refresh button works.

Comment: Ok, one step closer... if the app gets loaded through the "open with..." action it works. As soon as the user uses the app and switches ViewControllers (with storyboard & segues) the address changes and the updating with "open with..." stops working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As can now be deduced from your comments. It seems that your storyboard segues are instantiating a new instance of your "ViewController" class rather than returning you to your original. The original, however, is still the app delegate's `rootViewController`. This leads to you messaging an instance of your view controller that is not the one currently presented. Essentially, you are changing a label that you cannot see. There are a few ways to fix this.

- Change your segues so they take you back to the `rootViewController`:

It's probably the easiest, and will likely improve your efficiency. In your methods that cause a return use methods with words like `pop...` or `dismiss`.

- Use delegation:

Add a `urlLaunchDelegate` to your app delegate, and at appropriate times (`viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear:`) have your view controller set itself as the `urlLaunchDelegate`.

- Use the `NSNotificationCenter`

Have a notification like `MyApplication_LaunchURLNotification` that your view controller observes. You could add the `NSURL` as the object.

Comment: Thanks for all your help! I opted for the first option (pop/dismiss).

Answer (score 0):

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextView
```

Needs to declare a name

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextView *textView
```

You also need to link the textView in your IBOutlet as well.

Comment: sorry... was a typo... will edit post... I did this of course

Comment: And you are sure you connected it via IBOutlet?

Comment: yes - am sure other wise the other scenarios (i.e. refresh button) wouldn't work.

Comment: Why are you using _textView and not self.textView?

Comment: Why shouldn't I? I thought it was the same? I just tested it but `self.textView` has the same behavior.